# Is JNI capable of protecting source code (classes.dex) in an apk file?

Tags: android, encryption, apk, dex

I have an APK packaged with encrypted classes.dex file while the assets(image, text, etc.) are not encrypted.

Say that for me Protection of decryption key is not a problem, can I use JNI to decrypt the dex file into a bytearray and than load it?

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you're willing to write a custom `DexClassLoader` to load the class from the decrypted <s>byte array</s> *****. But why do you need JNI? You could perform the decryption in the class loader itself.

**EDIT**

*) Unlike the JDK, Android currently does not support loading classes from a byte array. You will need to write the decrypted class data to a temporary file, and load it from there.

Comment: Does DexClassLoader allow loading dexfile from a byte array?It takes path of the dexfile to load..should I override the method getResourceAsStream() for this purpose? I want to use JNI to make the decrptor more secure compare to normal Java Implementation

Comment: Sorry, wishful thinking for a feature that doesn't exist yet. I updated my answer.

Comment: But isn't that we can achieve the same i.e. loading from a bytearray using using DexFile?